# icCube: wsdl document for the xmla layer

Tags: wsdl, xmla, iccube

Is there available an URL to a WSDL document which describes the icCube XMLA services? How to access them and how to use its methods?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for an existing XMLA library instead of a low level one. For example [Olap4J](http://www.olap4j.org/) in Java or [ADOMD.NET](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123483.aspx) in .NET.

In case you really want to go the hard way, you can use [this](https://github.com/may-day/olap/blob/f3be2140486f39ff7caf0481059ed48969defbf8/xmla/olap/xmla/vs.wsdl) wdsl done some years ago.